# preg_match, how to access single value

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string

> "Dollar to trade at 1.35 usd, touched the weakest level in 2 months at
>   1.34 usd"

i  extract with two different pattern preg_match decimal number 1.35, 1.34 and 2.

```
$pattern = '/.\d+(?:\.\d{2})?((?<=[0-9])(?= usd))/';
$patterndate = '/.\d+(?:\.\d{2})?((?<=[0-9])(?= months))/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $new);
preg_match_all($patterndate, $str, $res);

foreach($new[0] as $k => $v) {
    $result = $v;
}

foreach($res[0] as $k => $v) {
    $date = $v;
}
```

I would like insert the value in differents column mysql but the $result contain two value 1.35 1.34 and i would like to access single value.
If anyone could help me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$result` contains only one value: the last value that was matched (1.34), because you overwrite `$result` in every iteration of the loop.

If you want to store all values, you should make `$result` an array:

```
$result = array();
foreach($new[0] as $k => $v) {
    $result[] = $v;
}
print_r($result); // it's an array that contains 1.35 and 1.34
```

Then put into the DB like that:

```
INSERT INTO ... (col1, col2) VALUES ($result[0], $result[1])
```

But make sure that you indeed get 2 matches

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Dollar to trade at 1.35 usd, touched the weakest level in 2 months at 1.34 usd" ;

$pattern_float = '/\s[0-9]+.[0-9]+\s/' ;
$pattern_interger = '/\s[0-9]+\s/' ;

$matches = array() ;
preg_match_all( $pattern_float , $string , $matches ) ;

var_dump( "FLOAT" , $matches[0] ) ;

$matches = array() ;
preg_match_all( $pattern_interger , $string , $matches ) ;
var_dump( "INTEGER" , $matches[0] ) ;

//use trim to clean data..
```

Answer (score 0):

Seperate it with explode, with " " deliminater.

```
$seperate = explode(" ",$result);
 echo $seperate[0];
 echo  $seperate[1];
```